Monorepo: cannot find module that is in root tsconfig paths + in current module's dependencies
My project structure is like this
project/
  packages/
    common/
      src/
        *.ts
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
    main/
      src/
        main.ts
      package.json
      tsconfig.json
  package.json
  tsconfig.json

project/tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@project/comon": [
        "packages/common/dist"
      ]
    },
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}

project/packages/some-module/tsconfig.json / project/packages/main/tsconfig.json (same)
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}

project/package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "some description",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/common",
    "packages/describe"
  ],
  "author": "L.S.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn workspaces run -Apt build"
  }
}

project/packages/common/package.json
{
  "name": "@project/common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "some description",
  "type": "module",
  "author": "L.S.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.11",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}

project/packages/main/package.json
{
  "name": "@project/main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "some description",
  "main": "dist/main.js",
  "author": "L.S.",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main.js",
    "start:dev": "tsnd --watch src --respawn --transpile-only src/main.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@project/common": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.12.11",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5"
  }
}

And now with this setup if I try to import something from @project/common in project/packages/main/src/main.ts, when I try to compile with tsc, it yells Cannot find module @project/common or its corresponding type declarations. (and I also checked that @project/common was build beforehand, so it's not the problem).

(Shameless plug) I haven't yet delved in your setup properly, but here's my attempt to implement a TypeScript monorepo with path aliases, maybe you can take something from it: https://github.com/parzhitsky/try-monorepo
